# How to find unused port in Ruby

Tags: ruby, port

I know I can find out used ports using `netstat -antp` on Linux.

How can I find out free port using Ruby? I know I can run `netstat -antp` and parse output but is there more simple solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `selenium-webdriver` in your Gemfile you can use its socket poller:

```
free_port = Selenium::WebDriver::PortProber.above(3000)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use a gem 'netstat'. So see it along the link https://github.com/davidw/ruby-netstat
Use it like follows:

```
Netstat.read_tcp # >> Array of socket, each of that formed as Hash
```